# Junit5 Tests not getting picked up with Maven, but runs fine in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Maven is not picking up Junit5 tests from my application. But when I run the tests via Intellij, tests are being picked up and ran fine. I could see that it's detecting Junit4Provider automatically. Also, I haven't specified maven-surefire plugin explicitly in my POM. I have tried specifying the maven surefire plugin explicitly with junit5 engine as dependency, but of no use.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ 
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO]
```

POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!-- Other dependencies here -->
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>IT</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/it/java</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-integration-test-resource</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: Intellij does not use maven to run tests unless explicitly asked for, as this is slow, but instead use heuristics to guess what you want.  Apparently it assumes your maven configuration is correct.

Comment: JUnit Jupiter requires at minimum surefire/failsafe-plugin 2.22.2 better use most recent versions of maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin... also strongly recommend move your integration tests into `src/test/java` and follow naming conventions...

Answer (score 1):

Your project contains dependencies to: `junit-platform-runner`
So Junit 5 tests are tried to executed by JUnit4 environment.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner

Please remove `junit-platform-runner` from your dependencies if you don't have a special requirement which is reasonable for your project.

---

By the way dependencies with scope `import` can only be used in   `dependencyManagement`

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#importing-dependencies

Comment: Thank you so much. Tests ran fine with Maven once I removed junit-platform-runner from the dependencies. And yes, junit-bom with import scope was declared under dependencyManagement only. I just mentioned here under dependencies to say that it's also one of the dependencies. Thanks.